# UnhandledPromiseEXception in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing the following error while running an ionic app.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or greater from App Store
(node:6853) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Please help me..